# vue-router redirects to login. Even with the unguarded paths it redirects me to the login

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vite

```
import {
  createRouter,
  createWebHistory
} from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import PublicPage from "../views/public.vue";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [{

      path: "/public",
      name: "PublicPage",
      component: PublicPage,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: false, // No authentication required
        roles: [], // No specific roles required
      },

      path: "/",
      name: "Home",
      component: Home,
      props: true,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        roles: ["Super Admin", "Admin", "Viewer"],
      },
    },
    {
      path: "/test",
      component: () => import("../views/Test.vue"),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        roles: ["Super Admin", "Admin", "Viewer"],
      },
    },
    {
      path: "/map",
      component: () => import("../views/Map.vue"),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        roles: ["Super Admin", "Admin", "Viewer"],
      },
    },
    {
      path: "/contact",
      component: () => import("../views/Contact.vue"),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        roles: ["Super Admin", "Admin", "Viewer"],
      },
    },
    {
      path: "/users",
      component: () => import("../views/Users.vue"),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        roles: ["Super Admin", "Admin"],
      },
    },
    {
      path: "/support",
      component: () => import("../views/Support.vue"),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        roles: ["Super Admin", "Admin", "Viewer"],
      },
    },
    {
      path: "/settings",
      component: () => import("../views/Settings.vue"),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        roles: ["Super Admin", "Admin"],
      },
    },
    {
      path: "/assets",
      component: () => import("../views/Assets.vue"),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        roles: ["Super Admin", "Admin"],
      },
    },
    {
      path: "/alerts",
      component: () => import("../views/Alerts.vue"),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        roles: ["Super Admin", "Admin"],
      },
    },
    {
      path: "/clients",
      component: () => import("../views/Clients.vue"),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        roles: ["Super Admin", "Admin"], //only super admin have access to the company list
      },
    },
    {
      path: "/labels",
      component: () => import("../views/Labels.vue"),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        roles: ["Super Admin", "Admin"],
      },
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "Login",
      component: () => import("../views/authentication/Login.vue"),
    },
    {
      path: "/register",
      name: "Register",
      component: () => import("../views/authentication/Activate.vue"),
    },
  ],
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !token) {
    next({
      name: "Login"
    });
  } else if (token) {
    const userRole = localStorage.getItem("role"); // implement this function to get the user's role from the backend
    const authorizedRoles = to.meta.roles;
    if (authorizedRoles && authorizedRoles.length && authorizedRoles.includes(userRole)) {
      next();
    } else {
      next({
        name: "Home"
      }); // or redirect to a 403 page
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

Even if I am entering link as /public or /register which doesn't need authentication it still redirects to the  /login. It was working fine when i develope it first. Recently i updated my project by npm update. console.log(to.meta.requiresAuth) returns undefined and console.log(to.name) return login. There is no other place i have defined any redirect or rewrite rules for this project.

Comment: It seems the routes /public and /home are in the same object. So /public doesn't exist and /home does. And it requires authentication
But I don't think it explains why the /register route...

Answer (score 0):

Public and Home are in the same object. So Home erases and overrides Public.

Also Home requires to be authenticated and have a role.

When you enter a route like /register, that is public and you have a token

- `if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !token)` => false
- `else if (token)` => true
- - You check if your roles are in *undefined* (/register has no role array). **you are redirected to /home**
    And since /home requires you to be logged, you are redirected to login.

You should first add `},{` between your Public and Home routes, and then do something like that:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !token) {
    next({
      name: "Login"
    });
    return;
  }

  const authorizedRoles = to.meta.roles;
  const userRole = localStorage.getItem("role");
  if (!authorizedRoles || !authorizedRoles.length || authorizedRoles.includes(userRole)) {
    next();
    return;
  }
  
  next({
    name: "Home"
  }); // or redirect to a 403 page
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Now even though i have entered 2nd if                                                            `code`  if (!authorizedRoles || !authorizedRoles.length || authorizedRoles.includes(userRole)) {
    console.log('2')
    next();
    return;
  } `code` the next() still takes me to the login page. Also,, I have changed the register path `code` {
      path: "/register",
      name: "Register",
      component: () => import("../views/authentication/Activate.vue"),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: false,
        roles: [''],
      },
    },`code`